# Error al intentar obtener una captura de pantalla: : "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF"

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot

Estoy tratando de obtener capturas de pantalla de mi dispositivo desde Android Studio en Windows.

Trato de acceder al dispositivo y obtener la imagen del emulador o dispositivo fisico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero recibo el mensaje:

> "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF"

Al parecer es el ejecutable adb.exe que viene con el  SDK API 26 ya que anteriormente no se presentaba este problema.

Intenté desconectar mi dispositivo y reiniciar Android Studio sin éxito.

He visto esta pregunta en el sitio en inglés,

[Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF Android Studio 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187695/unexpected-error-while-obtaining-screenshot-from-device-eof-android-studio-3-2)

pero : **¿Cómo solucionar este problema sin tener que reiniciar mi pc o Android Studio?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Este detalle puede ser solucionado en ocasiones reiniciando pero en otras ocasiones no ya que el proceso continua "vivo".

Al principio pensé que el problema sería el ADB pero el proceso del ADB se estaba ejecutando.

Una solución es detener este proceso e iniciarlo nuevamente.

Busco el proceso en el Administrador de tareas para detener el proceso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo tratar nuevamente de obtener el Screenshot y el proceso, o buscar en el directorio `/ platform-tools /` de mi carpeta de SDK de Android el `adb.exe` para iniciar el proceso nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]