# Comprobar si existe un directorio en bash script

Tags: bash

Qué comando de bash script puede utilizarse para comprobar si un directorio existe o no desde el shell?

Comment: Si tienes pensado realizar una pregunta con una respuesta para ayudar a los demas, es mejor que formules bien la misma, asi tal cual como esta podrian denunciarla como de baja calidad.

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo de como deberias hacer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/208243/107347 si te fijas en el enlace que te comparto el usuario creo una pregunta con una redaccion que se acopla a una pregunta valida incluyendo sus interrogantes. y luego publico una solucion.

Comment: Hola Orlando. no era la idea inicial incluir una respuesta. He mirado tu segundo  comentario y no entiendo tu ejemplo, me ayudaría más si me indicas qué ves mal en la forma de formular la pregunta para poderla corregir. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Comprueba primero si se trata de un enlace simbólico a un directorio, para evitar posibles errores:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then 
    if [ -L "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
        # Es un symlink
        # Código a ejecutar
    else
        # Es un directorio
        # Código a ejecutar
    fi
fi
```

Referencia: [How to check if a directory exists in a Bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839/1983854)

Comment: Gracias por la mejora, Alejo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar si un directorio existe en un script de shell se puede hacer así:

```
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
  # entraremos aquí si $DIRECTORY existe.
fi
```